# How to display only one x-axis labels in Highcharts synchronized charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, axis

I am using the Highcharts synchronized charts to display three different variables. However, in order to render cleaner graphs, I'd like to display the x-axis (which is the same for all three graphs) only for the bottom graph.

For that, I presume, I need to cycle at the end of the generation process through the charts and suppress the first two x-axis, kind like

```
for (i = 0; i < (Highcharts.charts.length - 1); i = i + 1) 
{
   chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
   chart.xAxis.labels.enabled = false;
}
```

[Here is the default fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/).

I don't succeed in getting this to work. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `xAxis.visible` property depending on the chart index:

```
success: function (activity) {
    activity = JSON.parse(activity);
    activity.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {

        ...

        Highcharts.chart(chartDiv, {
            xAxis: {
                visible: i === 2,
                ...
            },
            ...
        });
    });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cmdb5at0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.visible